# how to view/print all the characters in a font (mac ox10.12)?

Tags: fonts, mac

I'm trying to find a simple way to be able to view all the characters that are available in a font, and to possibly create a PDF sheet of those characters for reference.

Is there a way to do this these on MacOS? I used to use something called FontBook (not the Mac Fontbook, but a different one!). I'm using Suitcase Fusion to manage my fonts, by the way.

I also used to use PopChar, but I find it doesn't work that well and is expensive.

Thanks in advance!